# Merge with 0 observations

Tags: merge

```
function = merge(Data1,Data2 , by = "x")
```

Data1 : 13000 observations with 6 variables
Data2 : 5600 observations with 35 variables
I get 0 obs but all of my variables as expected
I can email the datasets

Comment: What language is this written in? Is the "merge" function provided by the language or library, or did you write it yourself? In either case, explain where it comes from and what it does. More context is needed before anyone can provide meaningful help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple my names had an extra space so one dataset could not merge with the other